# What does this Visual Studio shortcut mean: Ctrl +\, E

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to work out the shortcut for opening the error list. Visual studio says it is **Ctrl +\, E**. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means press Ctrl + \ together, followed directly by E.